# Javascript validation as trim val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why my current validation is not working with my checkbox inputs. Here is the code:

```
var validation = "";
var values = {};

if ($.trim($("#formDoor").val()) == "") {
    validation = "false";
} else {
    values['formDoor'] = $.trim($("#formDoor").val());
}                            
if(validation == "false"){
    return false;
}   

values["formSubmit"] = "";

<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" id="formDoor" value="A" />Acorn Building
```

Why is my current validation not working with my checkbox?

Comment: Why would the value of a checkbox ever change ?

Comment: Are you just trying to check if it's checked ?

Comment: If you want to use a boolean, you shouldn't put it in quotes, so use `false` instead of `"false"`.

Comment: The validation seems to not work......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox `val()` is always the same, no matter if it's checked or not. In order to "validate" the state of a checkbox, you can use `$('#formDoor').is(':checked')`, for example.

Your code should look like this:

```
var validation = true;
var values = {};

if (!$("#formDoor").is(':checked')) { /* <-- changed condition */
    validation = false;
} else {
    values['formDoor'] = $.trim($("#formDoor").val());
}
if (!validation) {
    return false;
}

values["formSubmit"] = "";
```